# how to increment in mvc without identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with mvc3, I have a form in that users fill out and then it gets e-mailed to me.I am trying to get an example of how I would create an ID (based on my own conventions) that I can use for different users based on that unique id. my form contains several fields like registration number(which is user created their own),name,country,and some other details.

This is the convention I am striving for:

[CountryCode]-[Registration number]-[Continuous Numbers].. How can i generate this Unique id in MVC3. Iam using following code... Here i want to increment value of num

```
public string uniq(Model model,string Uniquecode)
{
    var i= 100;
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", model.Country,i);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would ensure that the registration number is already unique. Otherwise, you don't need it. Why? Because it does not tell you anything. Why? Because it is not unique. Just like the name of the user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a table and store the incremented values as a flag value and get the last incremented value from that flag value table.

Answer (score 1):

You may try a hack like this one:

```
var id = DateTime.Now.ToBinary(); // Unique because there will be no more DateTime.Now in the future
var date = DateTime.FromBinary(id); // Getting back  the value
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a database. You can let the database manage your IDs. Generating unique identity numbers in a database is usually simple - you have [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) columns in SQL Server, and all other databases have a similar feature.

If you're not using a database, can generate a [unique GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) - that's easier than maintaining a unique count.

Comment: Nitpick: *generate a unique GUID* should be *generate a GUID*.

Comment: Not really, you can generate the same GUID twice. It's still called a GUID if it's not unique, nobody calls it GID...

Answer (score 0):

make the variable i as static and increment i after getting the result